# Recursive association with inheritance

Tags: sql, database, database-design

If my inherited table has recursive association does the foreign key point to the primary key of this table or the parent table?

In my scenario:

- Person inherits Employee.
- Employee can manage 0:many Employees and an Employee can have 1 manager. (recursive association).

Is this table correct or should the second constraint reference Person(person_id) instead?

```
create table Employee(
  person_id int not null,
  salary float not null,
  etype varChar(25) not null,
  manager_id int not null,
  dept_id int not null,

  primary key(person_id),
  constraint fkemp foreign key(person_id) references Person(person_id),
  constraint fkmanager foreign key(manager_id) references Employee(person_id),
  constraint fkdept foreign key(dept_id) references Department(dept_id),
);
```

Also the CEO has nobody managing him does that mean I need to compromise with my data integrity and allow a null value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the table is correct.  For the purposes of the hierarchy, managers are **Employees** (their **People** properties aren't really relevant here).

Secondly, you can make `manager_id` nullable and not compromise your data integrity.  Clearly, there are situations where an employee does not have a manager (i.e. the CEO), so it isn't really any sort of logical violation to allow `manager_id` to be null.

If it makes you feel safer, you could add a `is_manager bit not null` column to the `Employee` table, and then have a constraint that only allows a null `manager_id` if `is_manager` is true.